# Displaying file content in html page produces empty field

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, frontend

I am building a web application which will search for my .feature files (which are regular text files) and display their path along with the content. I am using Python and Flask. I searched the web for ways to display the file content and as you can see from the source I found 5 ways to do it. But the end html page renders the file content as an empty box. I know the files path is correct because when I enter a gibberish path, I receive "Not found" for this element. I suspect it's a security problem.
Source code of the template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Available scenarios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--<h1>Available scenarios:</h1>-->
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    <form id="scenarios_form" action="/run_tests.html" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Run">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="clickable"><td colspan="2">Available scenarios:</td></tr>
    {% for scenario in scenarios %}
            <tr><td><label><input name="selected_features" type="checkbox" value="{{ scenario }}"> {{ scenario }}</label></td></tr>
            <tr><td><embed src="{{ scenario }}" /></td></tr>
            <!--<tr><td><a href="file:///{{ scenario }}">Link</a></td></tr>-->
            <!--<tr><td><object data="{{ scenario }}"></object></td></tr>-->
            <!--<tr><td><iframe src="{{ scenario }}"></iframe></td></tr>-->
            <!--<tr><td><a href="{{ scenario }}" target="_blank">Click To View</a></td></tr>-->
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </form>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make

work or I need to do everythin in the back end and send text to the template?
The behavior is consistent over every browser and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: If you have scenario files with `.feature` file extensions, it does not appear that you are requesting the file with the extension in your `<embed>` element. try adding the file extension.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not appear..."? I am passing the full file path + the extension to the template:
            <tr><td><label><input name="selected_features" type="checkbox" value="{{ scenario }}"> {{ scenario }}</label></td></tr>
prints the path, file name and extension. Is there something I need to do differently for <embed>?

Comment: Can't tell that from your example. If that's the case I have no answer. Your example works in a simplified form outside of Flask (straight HTML)